# Input value If macro variable exists else some other value

Tags: dynamic, sas

The need is to perform valuation of a macro variable outside datastep and depending on the existence of the variable, perform insertion:

```
data my_dataSet; 
set ...
....
if %SYMEXIST(Variable_from_prior_code) = 1 then do;

    dataset_variable = &Variable_from_prior_code.;

    end;
else do;

    dataset_variable = &Some_default_value_from_prior_code;

end;
```

However, this fails at compiler when trying to run it as the " Apparent symbolic reference &Variable_from_prior_code." has not been resolved. Ie. the compiler checks the contents of the if statement even as the condition is not met.

I came up with silly work-around: to approach this from opposite directon, but feels more stupid than bag of badgers:

```
if %SYMEXIST(Variable_from_prior_code) = 0 then do; 

    dataset_variable = &Some_default_value_from_prior_code

    %let Variable_from_prior_code=0; /*Dummy value*/

    end;
else do;

    dataset_variable = &Variable_from_prior_code.;

end;
```

Any way to restrict the compiler from evaluating  content, which it shouldn't due to condition?
Or alternatively, more elegant work-around, which do not require creation of the variable?

Comment: You are mixing up macro logic (used to generate code) and data step logic.  If you wrap your code into a macro then you can use %IF to conditionally generate the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say, avoid macro logic unless necessary!  Here's a pure data step approach:

```
%symdel Variable_from_prior_code; /* make sure variable does not exist */
%let Some_default_value=test; /* populate macro variable */

data my_dataSet; 
  if SYMEXIST('Variable_from_prior_code') = 1 then do; /* use data step function */
    /* note variable name is quoted, else would reference a data step variable value */
    dataset_variable = symget('Variable_from_prior_code'); 
  end;
  else do;
    /* had to shorten this name to less than max allowed 32 chars */
    dataset_variable = symget('Some_default_value'); 
  end;
run;
```

As Tom mentions, you are currently mixing up macro and data step logic.  Macro is used to write data step code (so is essentially a program generator), and that resultant data step code is executed long after the macro statements are compiled / resolved / executed.

Comment: symget did the trick. Tested and confirmed to work. 
Agreed. macro logic is bad juju. However need is as it is. :( (To merge two legacy workflows and permission to edit only selected few files.´)